# .Net Core API ModelState errors with Angular 8 FormArray

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working with .Net Core 3.0 and Angular 8. I'm building a form using Angular's Reactive Forms and FormBuilder, with FormGroup and FormArray. Basically, I have two models which look like this in the .Net API:

```c#
public class Parent
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In Angular I'm using FormBuilder to build a form like this:

```ts
// In the component class
// this.fb is type FormBuilder
form = this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
    children: this.fb.array([])
});

// Later on, I build the form.children like this
for (var x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    this.form.get('children')
        .push(this.fb.group({
            name: [''],
            description: ['']
        });
}
```

Note the `[Required]` attribute on the models in .Net. So if I submit my form without values for the required properties, .Net returns a response which looks like this:

```json
"errors": {
    "name": ["The Name field is required"],
    "children[0].name": ["The Name field is required"],
    "children[0].description": ["The Description field is required"],
    // and so on
}
```

I can obviously tell my Angular form that the `name` field has an error, because if I loop through the errors in that response I can say `this.form.get('key')` where `key` is each key in the `errors` object. However, that does not seem to work for the `children` FormArray.

So far the only way I've been able to get it to work is by manually parsing the error keys. That feels very wrong though, because I'm having to manually parse the index values from each of the `children[index].fieldName` errors.

I'm aware of client side validation using built-in and customer validators in Angular. Those will also be in place, but I'd like to be able to utilize the API's 400 response in the event that something gets past the client validation.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to take the .Net HTTP 400 error response - specifically the `errors` object - and add those errors to the correct FormGroup within the `children` FormArray (e.g. children[0].name)? I suppose it's possible I'm using FormGroup and FormArray incorrectly due to lack of familiarity with Reactive Forms (this is my first time with them). But from the things I read, this felt correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's breakdown a couple of your questions and statements:

> Is there a way to map the .Net HTTP 400 error response directly to the Angular FormGroup

No, you cannot "map" an HTTP 400 response to an Angular component of any kind, I am not sure what you mean by this in a way. An HTTP status code should be checked by an if statement or perhaps a catch block is entered using some HTTP libraries that will throw for certain HTTP status codes.

> But from the things I read, this felt correct to me

I don't think you are on the right track with your code. It would be best to start by not doing PostBacks to handle error validation with Angular Reactive Forms or any web form validation for that matter. You should have client side validation that handles validating and ensures valid data posted to your APIs. Of course, you will still fire your server side model validation as well to verify that data is valid, you always do this with any post to an API, you run server side validation as you never know what client is calling your APIs nor do you care if the Request is valid.

You should be using [Reactive Form Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

*Do not get hung up on repeating validation code Client Side. ASP.NET Data Annotation immediately leads to this desire and thus ASP.NET MVC Unobstrusive Validation exists for Razor views. I have gone far done this path. NodeJs is a great solution because the Javascript for validation can be shared client side and server side. There is an expensive architecture called [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) that uses [Fluent Validation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) that has some ability to share server side validation client side but, in the case of Angular Reactive Forms, you still have separate code client side when using Angular Reactive Forms because really your Validators are the proper way to tell Angular Reactive Forms if a field is invalid. For .NET Core and Angular Reactive Forms, it is efficient and perhaps best just to have separate validation mechanisms for client side and server side *

Comment: I've clarified the question about "mapping" in the last paragraph. Also, I did include in an edit after the initial post that I'm aware of built-in and custom validators for Reactive Forms.

To summarize your answer, are you saying it's best to not worry about the server side validation while building my client, because I know that I should be implementing all of the necessary validation on the client? And the server side validation should really only be of use in the event that a different client calls my API?

Comment: You should always run the server side validation as well, I am saying from an approach perspective, keeping things simple, getting best value out of Reactive Forms, implement your client side validation separate from your server side validation. It will keep your engineering life easier is this case to not try and utilize your server side validation with your Angular app

Comment: I understand. I should develop the client side validation to prevent known invalid data, correct? Required values, min/max length, etc. Meaning the server side validation shouldn't drive the form's validity, but obviously needs to remain in place in the event that the client side validation doesn't catch everything?

Comment: Correct, that sounds right, you always run the server side validation, think about someone toying with your API and sending repeat 2000 character count descriptions to your database over and over again, or whatever, you always have server side validation. For your frontend, with your .NET stack, you will best be served to develop freely with Reactive Forms by not trying to consider or resuse your server side validation is main message I am trying to convey here to keep your development life more simple thus that makes more productive building

Comment: Absolutely. That certainly sounds simpler and more appropriate. I've already accepted your answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of assistance :)

Comment: Sorry my stupid question. If I have angular reactive form validation, so that means the input is always valid otherwise it can't be sent to the data to the server. Why we still need server side validation? Did you mean that client side validation can't be trusted?

Comment: Yes a bad actor client can submit a malformed HTTP request to your server, they do not need your form to do it, they can make their own HTTP request and send to your server, thus you need server side validation no matter what

Comment: Just wonder. How to create malformed HTTP request in real world? Say I use chrome, can I do it through Network Tab? I thought that was impossible in the real world since I have many input fields so in my application I don't have server side validation.